# Почему key в React нужен только в перечислениях?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, компоненты, jsx, diff

Была поставлена задача реализовать свою JSX factory. Из документации React мы знаем, что JSX транспилируется в вызов функции `React.createElement(type,props,child)`, где child выражено rest параметром (передает через запятую массив потомков). Но каким образом сравниваются текущее и новое древо? Ведь это абсолютно обособленные объекты.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>It's</p>
        <p>OK</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Кроме того, что является критерием невозможности частичного рендеринга без поля key в перечислении? Мы же можем поставить два блока p подряд и ничего страшного не произойдет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При получении child происходит ["уплощение массива"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) - для избавления от включений [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), которые возвращают массив. Далее сравнение элементов древ можно осуществить следующим алгоритмом:

1. Мы сравниваем key и type текущих сопоставляемых элементов
2. Если совпали, идем к родителям

   - Если совпали, повторяем действие
   - Если одного из родителей не оказалось, элементы не равны
   - Если не оказалось сразу двух родителей, сравнение истинно

Реализация данного алгоритма в псевдо-коде:

```
bool Element::equals(
    const Element* a,
    const Element* b,
    bool recursive=true
) {
    if (a->key!=b->key) {
        return false;
    } else if (a->type!=b->type) {
        return false;
    } else if (recursive) {
        const Element* parent1 = a;
        const Element* parent2 = b;
        while(true) {
            parent1 = parent1->parent;
            parent2 = parent2->parent;
            if (parent1==nullptr&&parent2==nullptr) {
                return true;
            } else if (parent1==nullptr&&parent2!=nullptr) {
                return false;
            } else if (parent1!=nullptr&&parent2==nullptr) {
                return false;
            } else if (!equals(parent1, parent2, false)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Критерием невозможности частичного рендеринга является наличие трех и более (в строковом представлении древа потомков) эквивалентных элементов подряд, так как при попытке определить изменения будут удалены последние, а не изменившиеся.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более подробно об этом явлении можно прочитать в [этом](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/quite/blob/master/docs/diff-render.md) репозитории.