# как jsx переводится в js код?

Tags: javascript, babel, jsx

Не до конца понятно как именно jsx транспилируется в js код. Во всех руководствах пишется что то вроде: 
"вот так пишем jsx  а теперь берем babel и происходит магия". Хотелось бы понять как эта магия устроена. Имеется ввиду как вот такой синтаксис:

```js
const div = <div id='JSX'> Example </div>
```

Превращается вот в такой:

```
var div = ('div', {id='JSX'}, 'Example');
```

Вопрос в том как правильно передать div в функцию для обработки не вызвав ошибки SyntaxError. Подходит только вариант со строкой:

```
tokenizer('div')
```

Но в функию реакта для рендеринга мы же передаем простой jsx

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/415377/

Answer (score 2):

Непосредственно JSX довольно просто заменяется вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прототип функции createElement имеет следующий вид (*мы передаем не функцию в `render`, а объект, созданный при помощи JSX factory - результат ее вызова*):

```
createElement(type: string, props: any, child: Element[]): Element
```

Для примера, я написал собственную реализацию JSX Factory

```
class JSX {
    static _indent = 0;
    static createElement(type = '', props = null, ...child) {
        return {
            type,
            props,
            child
        };
    }
    static render({type, props, child}) {
        const print = (type, props) => {
            const indent = [...new Array(JSX._indent)].map((c) => ' ').join('');
            console.log(indent, type, JSON.stringify(props));
        }
        print(type, props);
        JSX._indent += 2;
        child.flat(Infinity).forEach((child) => JSX.render(child));
        JSX._indent -= 2;
    }
}

JSX.render(JSX.createElement('body', null, 
    JSX.createElement('p', {text: 'Hello'}),
    JSX.createElement('p', {text: 'World'}),
    JSX.createElement('div', null, 
        [...new Array(3)].map((_, index) => JSX.createElement('p', {text: index}))
    ),
    JSX.createElement('div', null, 
        [...new Array(3)].map((_, i) => {
            return [...new Array(3)].map((_, j) => JSX.createElement('tag', {i, j}))
        })
    ),
))
```

В результате ее работы, можно наглядно посмотреть на преобразование вложенных `map` при использовании React...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как разберетесь с JSX, про применение изменений с виртуального на реальное древо можно почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1028948/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-key-%D0%B2-react-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)...