# Подскажите каким скриптом выполняется конвертация формы в PDF

Tags: javascript, скрипт, конвертация

Есть страница `https://auto.ru/docs/dkp/` , расскажите каким скриптом на данной странице происходит конвертация из формы в PDF файл. Интересует именно скрипт используемый на данной странице, просто может я его найти не могу.

Comment: никаким. Отправляется web-запрос на сервер с данными, указанными на web-странице. На сервере происходит генерация pdf, а затем он возвращается в ответе веб-запроса. Ты можешь открыть Network в браузере и посмотреть детали запроса

Comment: Спасибо, в таком случае можешь посоветовать подобное решение, чтобы с минимальными знаниями кода(php+js) можно было настроить. Я так понимаю там сложность будет именно в настройке формирования самого PDF

Comment: не знаю php. Знаю, что есть удобная библиотека на Java для генерации PDF по шаблону. Хотя я в ней не пытался заполнять многострочные строки (извини за тавтологию)

Comment: думаю, тебе нужно задать новый вопрос по теме генерации PDF на PHP или JS по шаблону. Но сначала проверь github на подобные проекты

Comment: https://printjs.crabbly.com

Comment: А есть где-то пример где показано как можно печатать форму после заполнения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы можем генерировать pdf без сервера используя библиотеку [React Pdf](https://react-pdf.org/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотреть ее в деле можно [тут](https://react-pdf.org/repl).

Comment: Спасибо, но как я понимаю тут мне нужно будет дополнительно устанавливать React, а это лишняя нагрузка да и не понимаю я в нем, чтобы было понятно у меня сайт на wordpress (phpfpm+nginx+mariadb), поэтому тут решение либо в сторону JS, либо в сторону PHP, но я так ничего толкового чтобы с одного клика заработало:) не нашел.

Comment: @HotNet У React есть синтаксис без JSX: его можно применить в связке с Wordpress

Comment: А можно ссылку где это рассказано доступным для домохозяек языком:)

Comment: @HotNet https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1059967/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-jsx-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-js-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4/1065267#1065267

По возможности, если вам не жалко, отметьте ответ как верный